# First div content of the page always get printed even I click on second, third div content print button

Tags: javascript, printing

This code is used for ordering system. Whenever a new order added to the page, there will be a print button attached to that order list. Let say when it has 5 orders listed on the page, whenever I click on the print button of each order, instead of printing that particular order details, it always print out the first order details. For example, when I click on print button of 3rd order on that page, it will print out first order details.

Below is the code that I'm using:

```
<iframe name=print_frame width=0 height=0 frameborder=0></iframe>
    <script>
printDivCSS = new String ('')

    function printPageArea(){
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("order-item-container");
        var i;    
            for ( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
    
                window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML=printDivCSS+elems[i].innerHTML;
                window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus()
                window.frames["print_frame"].window.print()
                break; 
            }
            
            return true;
            

}


</script>
```

And my print button is as below:

`<a  id="print_button" href="#" onClick="printPageArea()">Print</a>`

I have tried to print using this method, but it is showing same problem as well.

```
 <script>

    function printPageArea(){
var divContents = document.getElementById('order-op-<%= order_id %>').innerHTML;
            var a = window.open('', '', 'height=600, width=800');
            setTimeout(function() { a.close();}, 1000);
           
            
            a.document.write('<html>');
            a.document.write('<body> <h3>----- <br>');
            a.document.write(divContents);
            a.document.write('</body></html>');
            a.document.close();
            a.print();           
}

</script>
```

May I know how can I make it to print appropriate order detail, instead of jumping to first one?

Comment: My first question to you is this; does this line of code do what you think it's doing? 
`var divContents = document.getElementById('order-op-<%= order_id %>').innerHTML;`

Check to see if you're actually getting a new ID each time you want to click the function called `printPageArea` That might be your issue right there.

Comment: `printPageArea()` needs a parameter that tells it which order to print, which could be the ID of that order container.

Comment: Hi @Chris , Yes it is doing the correct action of printing the content, but just getting wrong content. I have inspect the printPageArea(), it doesn't seems to generate new ID.

Comment: Hi @Barmar , I have tried to enter the ID into printPageArea(), but it is still getting first order details to print.

Comment: There's only one function. If you're defining the functions in a loop, they're replacing each other and you only get the last one.

Comment: I tried to run again without using loop method and by adding ID into printPageArea(), unfortunately it is still getting first order details. But after I add the ID into  printPageArea('order-op-<%= order_id %>') and I inspect it on Chrome, the id is showing the same id as its respective order container, but it is just not getting the right content on print page. For example when I check on the ID of 3rd order container which is 'order-op-53', the print button within this container is showing correctly as printPageArea('order-op-53'), but it is still getting first order detail on print page